# Checking if a selector is true does not work properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I have several divs in HTML which contains different background images. If you click on a div, there is a selector, which will be set to true. For example, I have a div "jogging" and if I click on this, the background image change from black to orange and the selector jogging_selected will be set to true.

So far so good. Now I did a next button (#button_step3), which should set the display tag of this part to none but only, if one of the divs are selected.

It always goes to the "else-part" even if there is a selector which is true and I really don't get why.

#### UPDATE

I added console.log(jogging_selected); to the else part of the if query and he actually logs false. I really dont get why, because if I reclick the div, he changes back to black and he does this only if the selector is true.

---

Here is my javascript, CSS and HTML Code (I broke it down to the relevant parts):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
      
  var jogging_selected = false;
  var soccer_selected = false;
  var tennis_selected = false;
  var golf_selected = false;
     
  function setBackgroundAndSelector(childnumber, imagepath_black, imagepath_orange, activity_selector){
    if(activity_selector){
      $(childnumber).css( "background", imagepath_black)
    }
    else{
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging)" );
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer)" );
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis)" );
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf)" );
      jogging_selected = false;
      soccer_selected = false;
      tennis_selected = false;
      golf_selected = false;
      for(i=1; i<5; i++){
        if('.image_activitys:nth-child('+i+')' == childnumber){
          $(childnumber).css( 'background', imagepath_orange );
        }
      }
      activity_selector = true;
    }
    activity_selector = !activity_selector
   }
      
   $(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Jogging)", jogging_selected);
   });
     
   $(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Soccer)", soccer_selected);
  });
     
  $(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Tennis)", tennis_selected);
  });
     
  $(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Golf)", golf_selected);
  });
      
      
  // This is the function which does not work properly
      
  $("#button_step3").click(function() {
    if(jogging_selected || soccer_selected  || tennis_selected  || golf_selected){
      $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step2" ).css( "display", "none" );
      $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step3" ).css( "display", "block" );
    }
    else{
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      alert("Please select a sport");
      console.log(jogging_selected);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.image_activitys{
 margin: 5px;
 width: 128px;
 height: 128px;
}

.image_activitys:nth-child(1){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging); 
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(1):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Jogging) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(2){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(2):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Soccer) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(3){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(3):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Tennis) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(4){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(4):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Golf) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper_fitcalc_content_step2">
      
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Jogging"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Soccer"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Tennis"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Golf"></div>
          
  <!-- There are several more of this divs which I just deleted for my post -->
      
  <input type="button" value="to Step 3" id="button_step3"/>
      
</div>
```

Maybe you guys see why he always goes to the else part in the $("#button_step3").click(function(){}?

Comment: Have you checked the value of if(activity_selector)? Is it true?

Comment: Normally I would say it has to be true, because if I reclick the div, it change back to black. And it does this only if the selector is already true. Written here: 
if(activity_selector){$(childnumber).css( "background",imagepath_black)}.

But I checked it now by adding console.log(jogging_selected); to the else part and its actualy false?

#confused

Comment: Can you provide some working code to debug? create a fiddle or update the question.

Comment: Added some working code, which can be run as code snipped

Comment: Updated my answer. Which is working seems. @pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try following code. It may help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
      
  var jogging_selected = false;
  var soccer_selected = false;
  var tennis_selected = false;
  var golf_selected = false;
     
  function setBackgroundAndSelector(childnumber, imagepath_black, imagepath_orange, activity_selector){
    if(activity_selector){
      $(childnumber).css( "background", imagepath_black)
      return !activity_selector;
    }
    else{
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging)" );
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer)" );
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis)" );
      $(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf)" );
      jogging_selected = false;
      soccer_selected = false;
      tennis_selected = false;
      golf_selected = false;
      for(i=1; i<5; i++){
        if('.image_activitys:nth-child('+i+')' == childnumber){
          $(childnumber).css( 'background', imagepath_orange );
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
    return !activity_selector;
   }
      
   $(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
    jogging_selected = setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Jogging)", jogging_selected);
   });
     
   $(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
    soccer_selected = setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Soccer)", soccer_selected);
  });
     
  $(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").click(function () {
    tennis_selected = setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Tennis)", tennis_selected);
  });
     
  $(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
     golf_selected = setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Golf)", golf_selected);
  });
      
      
  // This is the function which does not work properly
      
  $("#button_step3").click(function() {
    if(jogging_selected || soccer_selected  || tennis_selected  || golf_selected){
      $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step2" ).css( "display", "none" );
      $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step3" ).css( "display", "block" );
    }
    else{
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      alert("Please select a sport");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.image_activitys{
 margin: 5px;
 width: 128px;
 height: 128px;
}

.image_activitys:nth-child(1){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging); 
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(1):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Jogging) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(2){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(2):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Soccer) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(3){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(3):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Tennis) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(4){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(4):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Golf) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper_fitcalc_content_step2">
      
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Jogging"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Soccer"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Tennis"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Golf"></div>
          
  <!-- There are several more of this divs which I just deleted for my post -->
      
  <input type="button" value="to Step 3" id="button_step3"/>
      
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following 4 variables are never going to be set to true.

```
var jogging_selected = false;
var soccer_selected = false;
var tennis_selected = false;
var golf_selected = false;
```

Why? Because you are only ever modifying the value of parameter `activity_selector` which is local to `setBackgroundAndSelector`. After `setBackgroundAndSelector` is done, `activity_selector`'s value is gone. I think what you are trying to achieve is [call-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) behavior, where modifying `activity_selector` modifies the boolean variable you passed in (e.g. `golf_selected`), but boolean parameters can only work using [call-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) in JavaScript.

You could change your approach slightly and do something like below using a global variable for state to achieve what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    

    var sport_selected = {};

    function setBackgroundAndSelector(childnumber, imagepath_black, imagepath_orange, activity_selector){
        if(sport_selected[activity_selector]){
            $(childnumber).css( "background", imagepath_orange)
            sport_selected[activity_selector] = false;
        }
        else{
            $(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging)" );
            $(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer)" );
            $(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis)" );
            $(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").css( "background", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf)" );
            sport_selected["jogging"] = false;
            sport_selected["soccer"] = false;
            sport_selected["tennis"] = false;
            sport_selected["golf"] = false;
            for(i=1; i<5; i++){
                if('.image_activitys:nth-child('+i+')' == childnumber){
                    $(childnumber).css( 'background', imagepath_orange );
                }
            }
            sport_selected[activity_selector] = true;
        }        
    }

    $(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
        setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Jogging)", "jogging");
    });

    $(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
        setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Soccer)", "soccer");
    });

    $(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").click(function () {
        setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Tennis)", "tennis");
    });

    $(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
        setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf)", "url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Golf)", "golf");
    });


    // This is the function which does not work properly

    $("#button_step3").click(function() {
        if(sport_selected["jogging"] || sport_selected["soccer"]  || sport_selected["tennis"]  || sport_selected["golf"]){
            $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step2" ).css( "display", "none" );
            $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step3" ).css( "display", "block" );
        }
        else{
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            alert("Please select a sport");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.image_activitys{
 margin: 5px;
 width: 128px;
 height: 128px;
}

.image_activitys:nth-child(1){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Jogging); 
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(1):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Jogging) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(2){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Soccer);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(2):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Soccer) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(3){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Tennis);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(3):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Tennis) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(4){
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/000000/fff.png&text=Golf);
}
.image_activitys:nth-child(4):hover{
  background:url(http://dummyimage.com/128x128/ff9900/fff.png&text=Golf) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper_fitcalc_content_step2">
      
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Jogging"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Soccer"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Tennis"></div>
  <div class="image_activitys" title="Golf"></div>
          
  <!-- There are several more of this divs which I just deleted for my post -->
      
  <input type="button" value="to Step 3" id="button_step3"/>
      
</div>
```

Note: I also think the following logic isn't what you wanted, as the selector will always be set to false. The code above also adjusts that to what it should be (I think).

```
            ...
            activity_selector = true;
    }
    activity_selector = !activity_selector
```

Comment: Alright. Unterstood that declarated and returned my variables in a wrong way. Works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

the variables of type boolean are used by value when used in a function and not by reference.
What has been done here is that the fourth argument of the function setBackgroundAndSelector passes by value the boolean variables. so the original variables(jogging_selected,soccer_selected,tennis_selected,golf_selected) are not effectively changed after the execution of the function, only a copy of them has been modified.
This is an alternatve solution:

```
var selection={jogging_selected: false,
soccer_selected :false;
tennis_selected : false;
golf_selected : false};
function setBackgroundAndSelector(childnumber, imagepath_black, imagepath_orange, activity_selector){
    if(selection[activity_selector]){
        $(childnumber).css( "background", imagepath_black)
    }
    else{
        $(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").css( "background", "url(jogging_black.png)" );
        $(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").css( "background", "url(soccer_black.png)" );
        $(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").css( "background", "url(tennis_black.png)" );
        $(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").css( "background", "url(golf_black.png)" );
        jogging_selected = false;
        soccer_selected = false;
        tennis_selected = false;
        golf_selected = false;
        for(i=1; i<5; i++){
            if('.image_activitys:nth-child('+i+')' == childnumber){
                $(childnumber).css( 'background', imagepath_orange );
            }
        }
        selection[activity_selector] = true;
    }
    selection[activity_selector]= !selection[activity_selector]
}

$(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(1)", "url(jogging_black.png)", "url(jogging_orange.png)", "jogging_selected");
});

$(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(2)", "url(soccer_black.png)", "url(soccer_orange.png)", "soccer_selected");
});

$(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(3)", "url(tennis_black.png)", "url(tennis_orange.png)", "tennis_selected");
});

$(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
    setBackgroundAndSelector(".image_activitys:nth-child(4)", "url(golf_black.png)", "url(golf_orange.png)", "golf_selected");
});


// This is the function which does not work properly

$("#button_step3").click(function() {
    if(selection["jogging_selected"] || selection["soccer_selected"]  || selection["tennis_selected"]  || selection["golf_selected"]){
        $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step2" ).css( "display", "none" );
        $("#wrapper_fitcalc_content_step3" ).css( "display", "block" );
    }
    else{
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        alert("Please select a sport");
    }
});
});
```